# utf (chinese char) covert to Hexadecimal format in php

Tags: php, vb.net, hex

I am passing my message to SMS api,

This is the documentation

> Normally Unicode Messages are Arabic and Chinese Message, which are
>   defined by GSM Standards. Unicode messages are nothing but normal text
>   type messages but it has to be submitted in HEX form. To submit
>   Unicode messages following Url to be used.

I tried `bin2hex()` there is not working for the output.

```
$str = '人';
//$str = 'a';

$output = bin2hex($str);
echo $output; 

//output
//人 = e4baba ； I would expect '4EBA'
```

I found a similar solution but it is in VB.net anyone can convert it?
http://www.supportchain.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/28/7/unable-to-send-sms-with-chinese-character-using-api

the sample i had tried, and it is work:-

> example of conversion : a converted to hexadecimal is 0061, 人 converted to hexadecimal is 4EBA

Comment: How did you try using bin2hex()?

Comment: Yes, in the question there, I already written I tried bin2hex, but not the result I want

Comment: Correct, I see that you used it, but my question asked *how* you used it.

Comment: ok, sorry for the miss understanding. I had posted how I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing has to do with encoding. Since these are considered special characters, you need to add some encoding details when converting to hex.

Each of these outputs exactly what you were looking for when I run them:

```
echo bin2hex(iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-10646-UCS-2', '人')) . PHP_EOL;
//Outputs 4eba

echo bin2hex(iconv('UTF-8', 'UNICODE-1-1', '人')) . PHP_EOL;
//Outputs 4eba

echo bin2hex(iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE', '人')) . PHP_EOL;
//Outputs 4eba
```

Pick whichever one you fancy.

If you want to convert back:

```
echo iconv('UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8', hex2bin('4eba')) . PHP_EOL;
//outputs 人
```

Comment: Sure, I just have to look up the right encoding. This may take a few minutes.

Comment: @Shiro I have added how to convert back.